# Does a battery pack exists which does not need the microUsb power connection?

Tags: gpio, power, battery

I'm building a small robotic car, which obviously needs battery power for it and the RPi. I've no problem with the battery pack for the car since it fits neatly into the chassis, but the RPi microUsb means the RPi power lead sticks out the side of the chassis.

What I'd like to know is there a battery pack lithium or otherwise that attaches to the Pi, providing power through the GPIO whilst still allowing full access to the GPIO?

Comment: There's loads around. One example of many is https://uk.pi-supply.com/products/pijuice-standard

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can power a pi with the gpio pins but you can easily DAMAGE YOUR PI.
Use a 5v power supply and connect the 5v end to any 5v pin and the ground end to any ground pin on your pi.

Comment: I know you can power the Pi via the GPIO as you describe, but I would like to know if there exists a power supply which will fit flush under or over the Pi feeding the GPIO pin, which does not block access the other GPIO pins.